# linux-bash read data from csv and sum up values conditionally

Tags: linux, bash, shell, csv, awk

Im new to shell scriptingand been working on reading data from csv. I have a csv file which contain data from line 10. The data is like

> ```
> 2016-12-12,22.5,56
> 2016-12-13,23.1,62.1
> 2016-12-14,16.3,76.6
> 2016-12-15,18.8,44.7
> 2016-12-16,17.6,53.2
> ```

I would like to get average of 2nd and 3rd column for only weekends [ when first column date is either sat or sun]. In this case i need to get averages for 2016-07-2 and 2016-07-3.

I have written a script which uses awk , but however its failing near looping inside first bracket

```
idealminTemp=15 #set ideal minimum
idealMaxTemp=25 #set ideal maximum
weekends=( "2016-07-2" "2016-07-3" "2016-07-9" "2016-07-10" "2016-07-16" "2016-07-17" "2016-07-23" "2016-07-24" "2016-07-30" "2016-07-31" )

awk -F"," 'NR > 9 {for i in ${weekends[@]} i= $1 ? MinTemp+=$3; MaxTemp+=$4 : MinTemp+=0; MaxTemp+=0 ; } END { ( MinTemp/(NR-9) >= $idealminTemp && MaxTemp/(NR-9) <= $idealMaxTemp ? 
print "Ideal" : print "Not Ideal" }' ./InputFile.csv
```

Comment: What do you think `${weekends[@]}` mean? I think you are using `shell` code style in `awk` code. Please, read the `awk` basic guides and learn about `awk`, because `${weekends[@]}` means nothing in `awk`. `weekends` is a `bash` array variable, not an `awk` array. The same reasoning for `idealminTemp` and `idealMaxTemp`.

Comment: What is the error message reported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't understand your script but you can follow this template to restrict the logic to any day of week

```
$ awk -F, '{date=$2;                              # copy of date field
            gsub("-"," ",date);                   # format date for mktime
            if(strftime("%u",mktime(date " 00 00 00"))>5)  # Saturday:6, Sunday:7
                  print $2,($3+$4)/2}' file       # print original date field and average

2016-07-2 13.55
2016-07-3 11.45
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you need to read the *csv* file, check which dates are either *Saturday* or *Sunday* and for either day, average the values that follow the date, you can do that in bash itself (making a call to `date` to check the day, and `bc` to handle the *average*). There is absolutely nothing wrong with using `awk` for the task, but be aware, bash can also do it for you. For example you can do the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS=, read -r a b c d; do 
    day=$(date -d "$b" +%w)
    if [[ $day -eq 0 ]]; then
        avg=$(echo "scale=2; ($c + $d)/2" | bc)
        echo "$b -- Sunday, average: $avg"
    fi

    if [[ $day -eq 6 ]]; then
        avg=$(echo "scale=2; ($c + $d)/2" | bc)
        echo "$b -- Saturday, average: $avg"
    fi
done <"$1"
```

Which simply reads each line (discarding the empty field at the beginning of each row) and then using `date -d "$b" +%w` (with `b` holding the 2nd field, date) to check whether the date is a *Saturday* or *Sunday* (day `6` and `0`, respectively). If it is a weekend day, the values (in the 3rd and 4th fields, `c` and `d`, respectively) are passed to `bc` to average.

**Example**

Using your data, the script would provide:

```
$ bash dayavgweekend.sh dayscsv
2016-07-2 -- Saturday, average: 13.55
2016-07-3 -- Sunday, average: 11.45
```